# Lowercase characters to Uppercase characters in C & writing to file

Tags: c, character, uppercase, lowercase

I am reading content from a file to be read into a char array in C. How could I change all the letters in the file that are lowercase to uppercase letters?

Comment: `ctype.h` has `toupper`.

Comment: Where have you got so far? what have you achieved? Are you able to duplicate the file content for example?

Comment: I was already able to account for the letters and write to a separate files but I wasn't sure how to overwrite the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible algorithm:

1. Open a file (let's call it A) - fopen()
2. Open another file to write (let's call it B) - fopen()
3. Read the content of A - getc() or fread(); whatever you feel free
4. Make the content you read uppercase - toupper()
5. Write the result of the 4-step to B - fwrite() or fputc() or fprintf()
6. Close all file handles - fclose()

The following is the code written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INPUT_FILE      "input.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILE     "output.txt"

int main()
{
    // 1. Open a file
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "rt");
    if (NULL == inputFile) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot open the file: %s\n", INPUT_FILE);
        return -1;
    }

    // 2. Open another file
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "wt");
    if (NULL == inputFile) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot open the file: %s\n", OUTPUT_FILE);
        return -1;
    }

    // 3. Read the content of the input file
    int c;
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(inputFile))) {
        // 4 & 5. Capitalize and write it to the output file
        fputc(toupper(c), outputFile);
    }

    // 6. Close all file handles
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer and good use of `int c` rather than `char c`.  Yet OP has not demonstrated much work to deserve this fine answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked and I was able to organize it pretty well, I appreciate it.

Comment: My pleasure! Have fun!